# Laravel migrate.I want to remove a column and then add another column, but this is an error

Tags: laravel, migrate

```
Schema::table('cms_myterms', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('created_at');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

But this is wrong。

In Connection.php line 664:

SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'created_at' (SQL: alter table `cms_myterms` add `cre   ated_at` timestamp null, add `updated_at` timestamp null)

In Exception.php line 18:

SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'created_at'

In PDOStatement.php line 112:

SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'created_at'

Comment: in a single call you can't drop and re-create same column. either add `updated_at` or use different call for dropping and creating.

Comment: Thank you @zahidhasanemon. Your comment solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the `updated_at` column.

```php
$this->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable();
```